# How to fix content on proper place in UIWebView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I m just trying to fix all the contents of html according to the device screen.
I have to put html data at proper place for iPhone & iPad in webview.

Please help me!!!

Comment: you should edit your question to explain your problem better... does your content look okay when you open your HTML in the Safari browser built into iOS ?

Comment: I m using UIWebView in Xcode and in that UIWebView i have to open certain URL's in the app and display their data on iPad and iPhone but unfortunately i m not able to do that

Comment: It is very hard to understand this question. For example, you say "Im using UIWebView in Xcode" - but that is meaningless. Do you mean that you are using a storyboard, and that you have put a UIWebView into a view in the storyboard? If this is true, how do you tell the Web view which HTML to display?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that this question is a very basic one.

Suppose that you have placed a UIWebView in a view in your storyboard, and you have set layout constraints so that the UIWebView fills the view.

Then

1. Add an IBOutlet to your view controller, and connect it to the web view.
2. In the view controllers viewDidLoad: method, tell the web view what to display. Here is an example:

   -(void)viewDidLoad {

   ```
   [super viewDidLoad];  
   NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];  
   NSURLRequest* r = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   ```

   [_webView loadRequest:r];
   }

This loadRequest: call is asynchronous, meaning that the page may not show up immediately.

If this is not answering your question, please add more information.

Comment: Hello,I m developing a app in which i m finding this issue.  How can I set content which coming from URL on UIWebView.I m getting content from url but as of now it is showing different on iPhone & iPad in the app.